# How are variables stored in memory in recursion?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I'm unsure about how variables are created and stored in memory during recursion. Below is an example taken from C Primer Plus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursiontest(int); 

int main(){
    recursiontest(3); 
    return 0; 
}


void recursiontest(int n){
    printf("Level %d : %#x\n", n, &n); 
    if(n < 4)
        recursiontest(n + 1); 
    printf("LEVEL %d : %#x\n", n, &n);
    return;  
}
```

Which yields the output:

> Level 3 : 0x3ce1f8bc
>
> Level 4 : 0x3ce1f89c
>
> LEVEL 4 : 0x3ce1f89c
>
> LEVEL 3 : 0x3ce1f8bc

It appears as though the "n" variable local to the original function call is of an address sequentially later than that of the first (and only) recursive call. Why is that?

When I call a function, aren't its formal parameters declared and defined in terms of the actual argument passed to it? Wouldn't that mean that the integer n local to the first call is created before the second (recursive) call? How could the n of the second call have an address earlier than the first call?

Comment: Use a *much* lower n value (like, -99) to really see a difference.

Comment: between the two addresses there is a difference of 32bytes. 4 bytes would be for the variable n. what are the remaining bytes for?

Answer (score 8):

This is because the local automatic variables created during the recursive function calls are stored on the stack, and the stack grows "down" from a higher to lower address on most platforms, including x86.  Thus a function that is called later in the process will have variables with a "lower" address than variables stored from an earlier function call.

Comment: +1 because this answer mentions that the variables are created with each function call

Answer (score 3):

Local variables (including function arguments) are stored in the stack.  The stack grows towards lower addresses, which is what you observe:

[image: Memory diagram]

Thus, the deeper you go in the recursion, the lower the addresses will be.

Answer (score 0):

This is because local variables are on the stack, and the stack is allocated from high memory to low memory. That is to say, the earlier a variable is defined, the higher it's address would be.